# Pivot table in MySQL or Postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, pivot-table

How do we pivot from

[image]

to

[image]

Reverse of that is shown at :http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table test (
    custname text, 
    computer numeric, 
    monitor numeric, 
    software numeric);

insert into test values
('Alison', 345.89, 123.45, 78.78),
('Jason', 435.34, 158.23, 243.54);
```

Query:

```
select 
    custname "Customer", 
    unnest(array['Computer', 'Monitor', 'Software']) "Item type",
    unnest(array[computer, monitor, software]) "Amount"
from test;

 Customer | Item type | Amount 
----------+-----------+--------
 Alison   | Computer  | 345.89
 Alison   | Monitor   | 123.45
 Alison   | Software  |  78.78
 Jason    | Computer  | 435.34
 Jason    | Monitor   | 158.23
 Jason    | Software  | 243.54
(6 rows)
```

---

If `unnest()` is not available you can use `union`:

```
select custname "Customer", 'Computer' "Item type", computer "Amount" from test
union select custname, 'Monitor', monitor from test
union select custname, 'Sofware', software from test
order by 1, 2;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, if I were to do this in MySql or Redshift (which doesnt have unnest function), how would I go about it?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, Klin:)

Comment: For generating the MySQL code:  [pivot blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot);